# Tensorflow: How to have saver.save() and .restore() in one module?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a module called `neural.py`

I initialize the variables in the body.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, length])
tf_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])
...
```

I save the checkpoint in a function `train()` after training:

```
def train():
    ...
    pred = tf.layers.dense(dropout, num_classes, tf.identity) 
    ...
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(tf_y, pred)
    ...
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
        for ep in range(epochs):
        ... (training steps)...
    saver.save(sess, "checkpoints/cnn")
```

I want to also restore and run the network after training in the `run()` function of this module:

```
def run():
    # I have tried adding tf.reset_default_graph() here
    # I have also tried with tf.Graph().as_default() as g: and adding (graph=g) in tf.Session()

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, "checkpoints/cnn")
        ... (run network etc)
```

It just doesn't work. It gives me either `NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key beta2_power not found in checkpoint` or `ValueError: No variables to save` if I add `tf.reset_default_graph()` under `run()`, as commented above.

However, if I put the exact same code for `run()` in a new module without `train()` and with `tf.reset_default_graph()` at the top, it works perfectly. How do I make it work in the same module?

Final snippet:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Start training")
    train()
    print("Finished training. Generate prediction")
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a typo, but `saver.save(sess, "checkpoints/cnn")` should definitely be within `with tf.Session() as sess` block, otherwise you're saving a closed session.

> NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key beta2_power not found in checkpoint

I think the problem is that part of your graph is defined in `train`. The `beta1_power` and `beta2_power` are the internal variables of `AdapOptimizer`, which, along with `pred` and `softmax_cross_entropy`, is not in the graph, if `train()` is not invoked (e.g. commented?). So one solution would be to make the whole graph accessible in both `train` and `run`.

Another solution is to separate them and use the *restored* graph in `run`, instead of *default* one. Like this:

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('checkpoints/cnn.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, "checkpoints/cnn")
  print("Model restored.")
  tf_x = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('tf_x:0')
  ...
```

But you'll need to give the names to all of your variables (good idea anyway) and then find *those* tensors in the graph. Can't use previously defined variables here. This method assures that `run` method works with the saved model version, can be easily extracted in a separate script, etc.